OpenVPN search domain not set in systemd-resolved by NetworkManager
I've got a running OpenVPN setup (server is an OPNSense firewall, clients are Ubuntu 22.04 / 24.04) using multiple search domains as well as a "suffix" domain (for example "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH net1.example.org" and "dhcp-option DOMAIN clients.example.org")
Started via commandline and using the "update-systemd-resolved" script everything works flawlessly, but when I import the config file (ofc network-manager-ovpn and network-manager-ovpn-gnome are installed) then resolvectl shows that the search domains are not set on tun0. The suffix domain is the only one which is available.
I've read a lot of tutorials and posts but still fail to get the issue resolved.
My configs:
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn.example.org 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

# SSL/TLS parms.
ca ca-chain.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key

### Control Channel
tls-version-min 1.3
tls-ciphersuites TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
### Data Channel
data-ciphers CHACHA20-POLY1305

### ciphers is deprecated and replaced by data-ciphers (and not usable in 2.6.x anymore!)
### Network Manager OpenVPN plugin uses this option on file import, however, to set the cipher for the data channel (apparently does not know about option data-ciphers)
cipher CHACHA20-POLY1305
#comp-lzo
verb 3


Do you have any specific ideas?
